# Parse array to get required data

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an input array like this:

```
Array
(
    [one] => one
    [two] => two
    [group1] => Array
        (
            [three] => three
            [four] => four
            [group2] => Array
                (
                    [five] => five
                )

        )

    [group3] => Array
        (
            [six] => six
        )

)
```

I want to extract following 6 strings from above array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => group1,three
    [3] => group1,four
    [4] => group1,group2,five
    [5] => group3,six
)
```

Any Idea? Is there any useful PHP function for this?

**I have tried something like this:**

```
function getStrings( $data, &$result, $parent = '' ) {

    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {

        if( is_array( $value ) ) {

            getStrings( $value, $result, $key );

        } else {

            if( $parent == '' ) {
                $result[] = $value;
            } else {
                $result[] = $parent . ',' . $value;
            }
        }
    }

}

$tree = array();
getStrings( $input, $tree );
print_r( $tree );
```

**Result**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => group1,three
    [3] => group1,four
    [4] => group2,five
    [5] => group3,six
)
```

Comment: try using nested for loop

Comment: Any code what you tied before?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: *"gimme teh codez"* won't give you solutions. Show your work.

Comment: @Pred In it's current state, it is a bad fit for any site, including Code Review.

Comment: @Mast you are right, my bad

Comment: @Pred: Ok. You asked me to show what I have tried before. So I have added what I have tried. If you don't want to review now please don't review. I will try to survive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data structure which is:

```
$data = [
    'one' => 'one',
    'two' => 'two',
    'group1' => [
        'three' => 'three',
        'four' => 'four',
        'group2' => ['five']
    ],
    'group3' => ['six' => 'six']
];
```

You can use Recursive function:

```
function make_implode($data){
    $rows = [];
    foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            //$rows[] = $key;
            $nestedData = make_implode($val);
            if(is_array($nestedData)){
                foreach($nestedData as $keyNested => $valNested) {
                    $rows[] = $key.','.$valNested;
                }
            } else {
                $rows[] = $key.','.$nestedData;
            }

        } else {
            $rows[] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $rows;
}

$data = make_implode($data);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,1).'</pre>';


  //prints
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => group1,three
    [3] => group1,four
    [4] => group1,group2,five
    [5] => group3,six
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

use a recursive function, similar to:

```
$a = array("one"=>"one","group1"=>array("three"=>"three"));
var_dump($a);
function recFor($a) {
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($v)) {
            $tmp= recFor($v);
            $res[] = $tmp[0];
        } else {
            $res[] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
$b = recFor($a);
var_dump($b);
```

This is just a quick and dirty example, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response.